# In Next.js how to solve Extra attributes from the server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

While rendering a canvas with specified height and with within a child component in a NextJs app, this error happens
I try to add this https://codepen.io/rban/pen/BaNgQqM?fbclid=IwAR3J4hFkI6jJH5WrNjqbBC4PrF7Sv_xknY0SicDf5GffqjsjOtGzfRe3ETE
Mouse effect in my Nextjs application, everything works fine until this error occurs due to the SSR and SSG of Nextjs. How can I solve this? I have already tried to import statically the effects as a component but canvas with and height still...

```
client.js:1  Warning: Extra attributes from the server: width,height
at canvas
at div
at MouseEffectRender (webpack-internal:///./components/MouseEffectRender.tsx:16:11)
at LoadableComponent (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/loadable.js:113:9)
at Home (webpack-internal:///./pages/index.tsx:40:11)
at PresenceChild (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/framer-motion/dist/es/components/AnimatePresence/PresenceChild.mjs:15:26)
at AnimatePresence (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/framer-motion/dist/es/components/AnimatePresence/index.mjs:72:28)
at MyApp (webpack-internal:///./pages/_app.tsx:21:11)
at PathnameContextProviderAdapter (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/router/adapters.js:80:11)
at ErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@next/react-dev-overlay/dist/client.js:306:63)
at ReactDevOverlay (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@next/react-dev-overlay/dist/client.js:858:919)
at Container (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:92:1)
at AppContainer (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:197:11)
at Root (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:380:11)
```

in this canvas tag

```
import React, { ReactNode } from 'react';
import { color_hover } from '../components/MouseEffect';
import { useCallback, useEffect, useRef} from 'react';

interface Props {
  children: ReactNode;
}

export default function MouseEffectRender({ children }: Props) {

 

     const handleMouseMove = useRef((event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {});
    
      handleMouseMove.current = useCallback((event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => 
       {
        color_hover(event);
      }, []);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        if (typeof document !== 'undefined') {
          handleMouseMove.current = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
            color_hover(event);
          }
        }
      }, [handleMouseMove]);
    
      return (
        <>
          <div className="theBall-outer">
            <div className="theBall"></div>
          </div>
    
          <div id="page" className="site">
          <canvas className="banner_canvas  " id="canvas_banner">  </canvas>
            <div className="top-title wow fadeInUp" onMouseMove= 
             {handleMouseMove.current} ></div>
             {children}
          </div>
          
        </>
      );
    };
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

What's probably happening is you are doing something with the canvas that's different on the server than on the client. Read more about it here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error

Make sure the canvas width and height is the same on the server as it is on the client until Nextjs finishes hydrating.

You shouldn't be using the useRef hook to store a useCallback value.

If you want something to run exclusivley on the client and not on the server stick it in useEffect hook. useEffects get called only on the client.
Never check for window or document on the server, it will error out.

```
const handleMouseMove = useCallback((event:React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
    color_hover(event);
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    //client side only
    //stuff that happens on page load after hydration is complete
}, [handleMouseMove]);

return (
    <>
      <div className="theBall-outer">
        <div className="theBall"></div>
      </div>

      <div id="page" className="site">
      <canvas className="banner_canvas  " id="canvas_banner">  </canvas>
        <div className="top-title wow fadeInUp" onMouseMove={handleMouseMove} ></div>
         {children}
      </div>
      
    </>
);
```